# Define a new Java template in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, jsf-2

Im doing the same thing everytime im creating a JSF ManagedBean class :

1. From eclipse IDE, click on menu File -> New -> Class
2. Mannually adding and importing @ManagedBean, @ViewScope, @PostConstruct, etc

Can i automate this by defining a new template, so it'll be as easy as File -> New -> My ManagedBean ? I dont want to break the existing default Class template.

I know i can do this with new xhtml, i can choose which template to use when creating it. But i still cant find this feature for creating a Java class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use my plugin to create these kind of classes easily. Please go to http://fast-code.sourceforge.net/ and install. Let me know if any problem.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your plugin. It looks interesting. I'll put it into practice after i get to finish my targets on schedule. Have a nice day !

Comment: No problem, you can check out the latest release. It also nice template mechanism : http://fast-code.sourceforge.net/templates.htm.